# How do I amend my cashier program code to show all the item list that I have purchased in a receipt.dat file?

Tags: c

I am trying to write a cashier program code that users may buy several items and after running the code, if I had purchased more than 1 item, it will be listed down accordingly in the receipt such as this photo example?

[image]

The current result I am getting is this which don't seem right.

[image]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    float price, amount, discount, amountToBePaid, cash, change;
    int quantity, counter=1;
    char decision; 
    FILE *fp;
    
    printf("============\n");
    printf("Happy Market\n");
    printf("============\n\n");
    
    printf("Input item #%d price: RM ", counter);
    scanf("%f", &price);
    printf("Quantity: ");
    scanf("%d", &quantity);
    fprintf(fp,"Input item #%d price: RM%.2f", counter, price);
    
    amount = price*quantity;
    
    printf("Total is RM %.2f", amount);
    printf("\n\nAdd another item? (Y/N) :");
    scanf(" %c", &decision);
    
    while (decision=='Y' || decision=='y')
    {
    counter +=1;
    printf("\nInput item#%d price: RM ", counter);
    scanf("%f", &price);
    printf("Quantity: ");
    scanf("%d", &quantity);
    fprintf(fp,"Input item #%d price: RM%.2f", counter, price);
    
    amount += price*quantity;
    
    printf("Gross total is RM %.2f", amount);
    printf("\n\nAdd another item? (Y/N) :");
    scanf(" %c", &decision);
    }
    printf("\n*******************************");
    printf("\nItem(s) sub total: RM %.2f", amount);

    if(amount<=100)
        {
        discount = (amount*10)/100;
        printf("\nTotal discount: RM%.2f", discount);
        printf("\nDiscount eligible is 10 percent");
        }
    else if(amount>100 && amount<200)
        {
        discount = (amount*15)/100;
        printf("\nTotal discount: RM%.2f", discount);
        printf("\nDiscount eligible is 15 percent");
        }
    else if(amount>=200 && amount<300)
        {
        discount = (amount*20)/100;
        printf("\nTotal discount: RM%.2f", discount);
        printf("\nDiscount eligible is 20 percent");
        }
    else if(amount>=300)
        {
        discount = (amount*25)/100;
        printf("\nTotal discount: RM%.2f", discount);
        printf("\nDiscount eligible is 25 percent");
        }
    
    amountToBePaid = amount - discount;

    printf("\n*******************************");
    printf("\n\nGrand total: $%0.2f", amountToBePaid);
    printf("\nAmount received: RM ");
    scanf("%f", &cash);
    change = cash - amountToBePaid;
    printf("Change: RM %.2f", change);
    printf("\n\n*******************************");
    
    printf("\nThank you, please come again!");
    
    fp=fopen("receipt.dat", "w");
    {
        fprintf(fp,"*******************************\n");
        fprintf(fp,"HAPPY MARKET\n");
        fprintf(fp,"*******************************\n");
        fprintf(fp,"Quantity:\t\t\t\t %d", quantity);
        fprintf(fp,"\nSub total:\t\t\t RM\t%.2f ", amount);
        fprintf(fp,"\nDiscount:\t\t\t RM\t%.2f", discount);
        fprintf(fp,"\n~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
        fprintf(fp,"\nGrand total:\t\t RM\t%.2f", amountToBePaid);
        fprintf(fp,"\nAmount received:\t RM\t%.2f", cash);
        fprintf(fp,"\nChange:\t\t\t\t RM\t%.2f", change);
        fprintf(fp,"\n*******************************");
        fprintf(fp,"\nThank you, please come again!");
    }
    
    fclose(fp);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You use `fprintf` to write to the file pointed to by `fp`. But you do long before you have initialized `fp`. You do it long before you open a file to write to.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new to programming. Do you mind explaining further so I understand it better?

Comment: After you read the input for `quantity`, you have the statement `fprintf(fp,"Input item #%d price: RM%.2f", counter, price);` By that time `fp` haven't been initialized, `counter` is initialized to `1`, and `price` have just been read. You do the same early in the loop `while (decision=='Y' || decision=='y')` as well.